# JNI function returning string is garbage collected?

Tags: java, c++, c, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

I have a JNI function in C++ that returns a Java String. Is this string garbage collected by the JVM?

```
extern "C" 
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL  
Java_com_playax_fingerprint_Echoprint_code(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring fileName){
  const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(fileName, 0);
  char* str1 = const_cast<char *>(nativeString); 
  codegen_response_t* response = codegen_file(str1, 0, 0, 0);       
  char *output = make_short_json_string(response);

  free(response);

  env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(fileName, nativeString);
  return env->NewStringUTF(output);      
}
```

Who is responsible for releasing memory of the `output` variable? Is the code above free from memory leak?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of something like this, but I am iffy on that, but it should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3879515/67566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it as

```
jstring result = env->NewStringUTF(output);
free(output);  // or whatever will release this memory
return result; // result does not need output
```

Comment: do I need to run free(nativeString) and free(str1) also?

Answer (score 3):

The Java string (i.e. the `java.lang.String`) you return from the JNI function is subject to garbage collection. The `char*` you supply to `NewStringUTF` is not, because `NewStringUTF` creates a *copy* of the contents in the new Java string. So if `output` points to memory allocated dynamically within your native code and is not freed by you in some other way, then you'll have a memory leak (or at least you'll have it if the native method is called repeatedly).